# How to check if MacBook battery is genuine?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, performance, hardware-recommendation

My white MacBook's battery has completely died, so I'm looking for a replacement.

It costs $150 from Apple, or about $70 for **allegedly genuine Apple batteries on eBay**:

[image]

I'm leaning toward this cheaper eBay option, but when I receive the battery:

How can I confirm if it is a genuine Apple product?

I am concerned with fire safety and so on.

**Update:** I bought the cheap eBay battery mentioned above, and it was an obvious fake.

Comment: Who is the manufacturer? that could tell you more about the quality. FYI: the premium stores have to charge premium prices to pay for they premium status. (but they get they battery from same manufacturer as you) hehe

Comment: @Borderline, it should be Apple... that's the whole question

Comment: Even if the picture on Ebay is genuine, the battery you will finally get may be faked.

Comment: I believe that in System Profiler/System Information, you can click Power and see the manufacturer for the battery from there. My MacBook Pro (with a non-removable battery) has an SMP battery, but I believe older MacBook batteries use DP. If the manufacturer of the battery is not one of these manufacturers, then it's probably a fake.

Comment: Since my previous answer was deleted?, let me be more clear. That picture you are showing, shows a real Apple product. If you still have doubts, call Ebay to verify. It is they obligation to do so. I could help you further if you disclose the seller from ebay.

Comment: Interesting idea about calling eBay, and [here is one battery I've found](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Genuine-Apple-Battery-Macbook-13-White-A1185-A1181-MA699-MA566G-A-MB063J-A-/290860153201) (there's many others)

Comment: @patrix, how can you be so sure?

Comment: I ain't, but neither can you. Nothing prevents the seller from sending non-Apple batteries. Most buyers won't notice/complain and the ones who do get a replacement -> doesn't impact ratings. So if you want to be sure, get one from Apple.

Comment: eBay cannot verify if this product is real, many fake products are sold over eBay.

Comment: BS, ebay is legally obligated to verify that a seller is not selling stolen items, or intelectual property items. They make the seller responsible.

Comment: Where do you get the "many fake products are sold over ebay" ? If you know something concrete lets do some business together and sue ebay for lots of money. Reading they extensive T&C, they are very careful not to do what you are claiming, since they would be out of business fast.

Comment: @Baumr, yes call them ans say you want the sellers verification, since you have doubts the product is genuin.

Comment: Since you liked my idea about contacting ebay, do I get cudos ? I looked up the seller, and it looks normal. Notice the battery can not be shipped to USA.

Comment: @patrix, well, I don't mind sending it back and getting a full refund (eBay policy)

Comment: Reading your update, you most likely can accept my answer as stated "If it looks to good to be true, it most likely is."

Answer (score 4):

You can't be sure unless you buy it from a Premium Reseller or an Official Apple Store. The difference in price makes me think that this is one of the many fake ones around.

My golden rule on this:
If it looks to good to be true, it most likely is.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, they are right. eBay is known to sell knockoffs. At less than 50% off the original price, I'd wager that they aren't legitimate batteries, won't carry a one year warranty, or have the same charge capacity as ones sold by Apple.

Comment: @cksum, I didn't down-vote, but this post didn't provide an answer to how one can check — so the charge capacity will be an indicator if it's genuine or not? How can I check the warranty status — do batteries have serial numbers?

Comment: Yes it does provide an answer; the best answer actually: you can't. You cannot verify if it's a true battery made by Apple unless you have it in your hands. And even then, it may not be within an Apple employees means to do so (they don't tend to have access to serial number databases). Then there is the question of whether you will actually receive the product pictured in the ad. Like I said, I seriously doubt you will receive an authentic Apple battery for 60% less than retail.

Comment: @cksum, ah, to be clear, I wasn't asking about checking before buying but after (since I can return it if it's non-genuine).

Comment: @Baumr call Apple and ask them if they can verify the authenticity of a battery by the serial/firmware number. That's your best bet. Something tells me they won't be able to, but let us know if they can.

Comment: It would be more efficient if coments are based on facts, not opinions, Fact is that the buyer and seller are protected by ebay T&C. Fact is if you pay by PayPall you get additional protection. With that said, yes, there are many crocks in the world, but usually they are not so stupid to tray to sell fake products on ebay. Fact is that seller has a decent reputation on ebay. Golden Rule or not, this is clean business.